# Как изменить размер svg иконки (html,css)?

Tags: html, css, svg

```
Код html:
<div class="header-logo"><img src="img\logo.svg" alt=""> </div> 
Код css:
.header-logo {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: [Попробуйте это (Первый ответ).](https://qna.habr.com/q/539686)

Comment: .header-logo img{ваши стили}

Answer (score 2):

Ваша иконка равна размеру `<img>`, следовательно его размер и нужно менять

```html
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2893/2893003.svg" width="16">
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2893/2893003.svg" width="64">
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2893/2893003.svg" width="128">
```